# Electric field and electric potential of a point charge in 2D and 1D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law, spacetime-dimensions, coulombs-law

in 3D, electric field of a piont charge is inversely proportional to the square of distance while the potential is inversely proportional to distance. We can derive it from Coulomb's law.
however, I don't known how to derive the formula in 2D and 1D. I read in a book that electric potential of a point charge in 2D is proportional to the logarithm of distance.
How to prove it?

Answer (score 10):

The Coulomb potential has the following forms for a positive charge in each dimensionality:
\begin{align}
    \Phi_{\operatorname{1-d}}(r) &= -\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0} r, \\
    \Phi_{\operatorname{2-d}}(r) &= -\frac{\lambda}{2\pi \epsilon_0} \ln(r),\ \mathrm{and} \\
    \Phi_{\operatorname{3-d}}(r) &= \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left(\frac{1}{r}\right).
\end{align}
The reason for this is that the electric field, defined as $-\nabla\Phi$ in general and $-\dfrac{\partial\Phi}{\partial r} \hat{r}$ in this case, times the measure of the boundary of a "ball" has to be a constant. In 1-d, a ball is a line and the measure of its boundary is just the number of points on its ends (i.e. 2). In 2-d the ball is a circle and the measure of its boundary is the circumference (i.e. $2\pi r$). In 3-d the ball is a sphere and the measure of its boundary is the sphere's surface area ($4\pi r^2$). Notice that those are exactly the quantities in the denominator when we calculate the electric field from the potentials:
\begin{align}
    \vec{E}_{\operatorname{1-d}}(r) &= \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}  \left(\frac{\hat{r}}{2}\right), \\
    \vec{E}_{\operatorname{2-d}}(r) &= \frac{\lambda}{\epsilon_0} \left(\frac{\hat{r}}{2\pi r}\right),\ \mathrm{and} \\
    \vec{E}_{\operatorname{3-d}}(r) &= \frac{q}{\epsilon_0} \left(\frac{\hat{r}}{4\pi r^2}\right).
\end{align}

The name of the law that implies this is known as Gauss's law.

Comment: I was wondering about the divergence of -ln(r) after r = 1 in 2D. Can we still use electrostatic after r = 1 ? What does it mean?

Comment: @projesh the divergence happens at $r=0$, just like in 3D. $r=1$ is where the natural logarithm switches sign, which is meaningless because it can be moved by adding a constant to the potential.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused. Even if you add a large number, at $x \to \infty, -ln(x)$ is undefined and does not go to zero like 3D. Does it mean it can only be used up to a certain length scale depending on the constant?

Comment: @projesh That problem happens in 1-d, too. The potential goes to zero at infinity only for 3-d or higher. It is just a fact that 1-d is zero at $r=0$ and goes to $\infty$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$, 3-d and higher goes to $0$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$ and goes to $\infty$ as $r\rightarrow 0$, and 2-d goes to infinity at both ends.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Can you please comment on the numerical values and on the dimensional analysis of the "charges" $\sigma$, $\lambda$ and $q$ and of the vacuum permittivity $\epsilon_0$, i.e. how these changes with the dimensionality of the system. From what you've written, it seems that $\epsilon_0$ is always the same (both its numerical value and its dimension, i.e. 8.854 F/m, no matter of the dimensionality of the system).

Comment: @SeanE.Lake, I've realized that maybe this constitutes a question on its own, so I've opened a new post. I hope you will take a look. Thanks! https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/472451/electrostatic-in-2d-dimensional-analysis

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to use Gauss' law.

Suppose space is a 2d plane (Flatland!), and that there's a charge $q$ sitting at the origin.  Gauss' law says that if we enclose the charge in a 1-sphere $S$ (aka, a circle), then we must have
$\int_S \langle \vec{E} , \vec{n}\rangle  = 2 \pi q$ (in convenient units),
where $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector to the circle.  If you assume $\vec{E}$ is rotationally symmetric, i.e., $\vec{E} = E(r) \hat{r}$, this turns into
$E(r) 2\pi r = 2\pi q$, implying that $E(r) = q/r$.  Integrating a field that goes like $1/r$ gives you a logarithmic potential.

You can also uses Gauss' law in 1d, enclosing the charge in a $0$-sphere (two points, equidistant from the origin).  I'll leave it to you to try that one.

Comment: Gauss' law is one of Maxwell's equations: $\vec{\nabla}\dot{}\vec{E} = \mbox{constant} \times  \rho$.  It's fundamental, not derived.  If you integrate both sides of this equation over a volume, and then apply the divergence theorem, you'll get the integral I used.

Comment: @trhyt:  You seem awfully sure of yourself here.  But Maxwell's equations apply in situations where the Newtonian force law implicit in Coulomb's law has long since broken down.

Comment: @user1504, the first integral you use has a factor of $2\pi$ which shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Chris:  "In convenient units"

Comment: Oh yes I didn't see that, my bad.

Comment: @Chris:  No big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Deriving the electric field for a 2D world can be done in several ways. It would depend on what behavior of the electrostatic interaction you want to preserve in that world.

I you asked Coulomb, when he published his expression for the interaction, he would probably have said that the expression should be the same ($1/r^2$) just that the distance $r$ would only involve the $x$ and $y$ dimensions $r^2=x^2+y^2$.

However, when Gauss found that the flux integral is proportional to the charge enclosed by it, then is not so easy to answer. Because if you assume a 2D electron to have a $1/r^2$ field, then such world would not obey Gauss law. And if you impose that world to follow Gauss law, then  Coulomb living in this 2D world would have found a $1/r$ law instead.

So which of the two properties is more fundamental? In my opinion, Gauss law is, but I have no way to prove that since there is no 2D world to experiment with.

**My answer to your question** the book you read based its statement about the point charge's electric potential in a 2D by tacitly assuming that Gauss law holds for any world regardless of the dimensions. But there is no proof of its veracity.

Answer (score -1):

Irrespective of the dimensions, Poisson equation is always true. That is, if $\phi$ is the electric potential and $\rho$ is the charge density then, $\nabla^2\phi = \rho/\epsilon_0$. The Green's function of this equation satisfies $\nabla^2 G(\vec{x},\vec{x}^\prime) = \delta(\vec{x} - \vec{x}^\prime)$.

A Fourier transform of this equation is $k^2G(\vec{k}) = 1$ or $G(\vec{k}) = 1/k^2$. A inverse 3d  transform will give $1/r$ and an inverse 2d transform will give $\log r$ dependence. One can do the mathematics for 1d case as well to get a $r$ dependence.

The key point is that the Fourier transform of the Green's function of the Laplacian in any dimensions is $1/k^2$. The potential due to a point charge is just the inverse Fourier transform of $1/k^2$ in appropriately dimensioned space.

Comment: Given a little tensor machinery, you can give $\nabla$ its own vector Green's function also. Much less circuitous, in my mind, than having to backtrack to potentials.

Comment: @hlew We believe Poisson equation to be valid in any dimensions because it follows from a) Gauss law and b) the fact that electrostatic field can be expressed as a gradient of a scalar potential. The latter two facts are *assumed* to be true in any dimensions.

Comment: @Muphrid I don't know the technique you mentioned. Would you mind giving some more details?

Comment: @hlew The convenience of Poisson equation is that it is about a scalar field, as opposed to a vector field. And for the problem at hand, the solution is formally the same in all dimensions - inverse Fourier transform of $1/k^2$. Finally, it is a matter of taste whether to use Gauss law of Poisson equation.

Comment: I disagree that "Irrespective of the dimensions, Poisson equation is always true."  We've never found a universe with a different number of dimensions, so we can't say for sure how physics would work in such a universe.  There are inequivalent ways to generalize the know laws of physics into different numbers of dimensions, so you need to state your assumptions whenever you do so.