# Electrostatics Boundary condition for 2D problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, boundary-conditions

[image]

[image]

The 4 conditions above are what I am being taught, and I am aware of the usual boundary conditions of electric field and potential, but that links to surface charge density, and I was wondering how do I solve it in 2D case, where in this question, they ask for linear charge density, how should I link the boundary conditions equations to get linear charge density?

Comment: What do you mean with E_2n and E_1n?

Comment: n means normal to the boundary, t means tangential to boundary

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134780/discussion-on-question-by-helloworld-electrostatics-boundary-condition-for-2d-pr).

Answer (score 0):

In the boundary condition
$$
\frac{\partial {V_{above}}}{\partial {n}}-\frac{\partial {V_{below}}}{\partial {n}}=-\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}
$$
you have $V_{above}=0$ and the normal points in the $y$ direction.
$$
\sigma=\epsilon_0\frac{\partial {V}}{\partial {y}}
$$

Comment: I think it can not be this way. σ is surface density, not linear density. The equations he gave are 3D equations, and the question was about transforming them, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:** just replace $\sigma$ with $\lambda$ and everything's the same otherwise.

In 2-D, the integral form of Gauss's Law is still
$$
\frac{Q_\text{enc}}{\epsilon_0} = \oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{a}.
$$
but now the integral is over a closed *loop* (rather than a surface, with $d\vec{a}$ and $Q_\text{enc}$ refers to the charge enclosed in an *area* (not a volume).

To figure out how this relates to the discontinuity in $V$ at a boundary, we imagine taking as our integration volume a narrow rectangle, with two longer sides of length $\ell$ running parallel to the the boundary at a distance $\pm \epsilon$ inside & outside, and two short sides connecting the ends of the longer sides.  In other words, we take the 2D analog of a "Gaussian pillbox".  By the same logic as in the 3D case, we have
$$
\frac{\lambda \ell}{\epsilon_0} = \ell(\vec{E}_1 \cdot \vec{n}) - \ell (\vec{E}_2 \cdot {n}) 
$$
where $\hat{n}$ is a unit normal pointing from region 2 into region 1.  The factors of $\ell$ cancel, and since we have $\vec{E}_1 \cdot \hat{n} = - \partial V_1/\partial n$, we conclude that
$$
- \frac{\lambda}{\epsilon_0} = \frac{\partial V_1}{\partial n} - \frac{\partial V_2}{\partial n},
$$
just as we would expect from naïvely replacing $\sigma \to \lambda$.

Comment: Where did you read that in 2-D that was the Gauss's Law? I think it is not that.

Comment: @MarcBarceló:  It probably depends on how you define the units of charge and of $\epsilon_0$.  Certainly the natural generalization is that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} \propto \sigma$, where $\sigma$ is charge per area.  My version sets the proportionality constant to be $1/\epsilon_0$.  A different proportionality constant would change the $\epsilon_0$ in my result, but the fact that $\Delta (\partial V/\partial n) \propto - \lambda$ should still hold.

Comment: But E·da implies the vector of area goes out of the screen and needs a third dimension, but as you are using only two you can not define the gauss's law in that way.Here you can see information about gauss law in 2-D : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206911/what-is-gausss-law-in-two-dimensions

Comment: @MarcBarceló: My $d\vec{a}$ is equivalent to the $\hat{n} dl$ there.  (Also, are you implying that taking the dot product of vectors requires a third dimension?  It's perfectly possible to define a dot product in 2D.)

Comment: No, I am not, but you can not define the normal vector of a surface in 2-D. Apart from that, you can not substitute surface density with linear density.

Comment: @MarcBarceló:  In 2D, the infinitesimal "normal vector" from a closed vector would be the vector that points outward from the curve and is at right angles to it.   That's what I mean by $d\vec{a}$.  It's not proportional to area, of course, but I couldn't come up with a better notation for it (using $\vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l}$ would have been even more confusing.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134801/discussion-between-michael-seifert-and-marc-barcelo).

Comment: That is what I tried at first too because I can’t link elsewhere. But I am unsure how correct is this. Since Somehow I couldt find the BC for 2D problems